# Asp.net web api returns every json object instead of list specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

Have a api call to return a list of bookings. The problem is its returning every json object from the database. It's returning all the json objects it seems like every json object from the databse
here is my code
Api Controller

```
          private mechanic_trackerEntities db = new mechanic_trackerEntities();

          // GET api/Example
          public IEnumerable<booking> Getbookings()
          {
          var bookings = db.bookings;
          return bookings.AsEnumerable();
          }
```

webapi config

```
             var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
             json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
             Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

             .Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: And where do you set filter in case to not show all in Db? I see only `db.bookings`

Comment: i want all the booking but it returns all the results from the database. Things not related to bookings.

Comment: For this to happen your 'Booking' class would need to have properties relating to everything in your database? If it it I'd recommend not sending this class out but mapping it to a DTO with only the data you require. Also, are you using an ORM like Entity Framework to handle your Data Access? Because this shouldn't load everything unless a rule is set up to do otherwise (see lazy-loading).